# unresolved external symbol (LNK 2001) error with pcap functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libpcap, unresolved-external, winpcap

I know how to fix typical LNK2019 errors in MSVS (2013) but I'm having some extra trouble when trying to use winpcap..

I installed winpcap from [this site](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm) (a couple times, actually), which supposedly installed the necessary .dlls I need, and I also installed the developer kit and pointed the linker to it as so: [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Camzq.png), [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v89ox.png).

I placed `WIN32` in my preprocessor directives (or rather, defines), which took away compilation errors. However, when I run the test code at the bottom of this post, I get [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyNVH.png).

Test code here: http://pastie.org/10730081

Comment: You are pointing the linker to both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of the library files. If they did not use different names, you will have a problem. The linker can't find the right functions. Match up the "Library Directories" with your project configuration ("Win32"/"x64").

Comment: If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: Well, it's compiling and linking now, and I'm getting correct output, so yep

Comment: Okay, done. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Camzq.png), you have added the paths to *both* the 64-bit and 32-bit library files. If the developers of the library were not careful to use different names for their 64-bit and 32-bit editions, then the linker won't be able to find the right functions.

It is searching first in the 64-bit folder (because that's the one you have listed first), but you are compiling the application targeting a 32-bit architecture (the "Win32" project configuration is active).

The fix is simple: make sure that you have matched up the "Library Directories" with your project configuration:

Win32 → `C:\code\C++\libs\WpdPack\Lib\`
x64 → `C:\code\C++\libs\WpdPack\Lib\x64\`